# Problem building STLport NDK r5/ Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, stlport

I'm trying to build STLport for Android. I got the following steps, but they are not working:

1 - Clone STLport repository using:

git clone git://stlport.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/stlport/stlport

2 - Configure environment using :

```
./configure --target=arm-eabi --with-extra-cxxflags="-fshort-enums" 
            --with-extra-cflags="-fshort-enums"
```

3 - From src directory build it using

make SYSROOT"{MY NDK path}/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/" release-static

But I got the following errors:

```
In file included from ../stlport/stl/_alloc.h:45,
                 from ../stlport/memory:29,
                 from dll_main.cpp:41:
../stlport/stl/_new.h:45:24: error: new: No such file or directory
In file included from ../stlport/stl/_limits.h:36,
                 from ../stlport/limits:29,
                 from dll_main.cpp:48:
../stlport/stl/_cwchar.h:26:30: error: cstddef: No such file or directory
In file included from ../stlport/stl/_utility.h:35,
                 from ../stlport/utility:35,
                 from dll_main.cpp:40:
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: 'declval' was not declared in this scope
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: 'declval' was not declared in this scope
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'decltype' with no type
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'decltype'
../stlport/type_traits:889: error: template declaration of 'int std::tr1::detail::decltype'
../stlport/type_traits:942: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'decltype' with no type
../stlport/type_traits:942: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member 'decltype'
../stlport/type_traits:942: error: template declaration of 'int std::tr1::detail::decltype'
make: *** [obj/arm-eabi-gcc/so/dll_main.o] Error 1
```

Is there any include dir or configuration I´m missing?

Thanks,

Sergio

Answer (score 2):

Android NDK r5 now has STL support, just add `APP_STL := stlport_static`to your `Android.mk` file, valid options for `APP_STL` variable are;

- stlport_static
- stlport_shared
- gnustl_static

Note that only `gnustl_static` variant supports exceptions.

Comment: Hi. I´m trying to build STLport as it is a pre-requisite for another library I´m trying to build. This library is a 3rd party library that has no Android.mk, just a regular Makefile. Is there any other way to set APP_STL in order to enable STL support on it? I have tryied to add the include files and stlport_static directly on the Makefile (adding them to -I and -l parameters). The build went a little bit further but them failed, so maybe this changes were not enough.

Answer (score 0):

The last version on git seems to be broken. Try use a previous version (I've used the one from Wed, Dec 1st 2010 and it worked fine).

Answer (score 0):

I've manage to compile STL-Port on Android NDK R3 using STLPort GIT repository. A few "adaptations" are necessary however. You can find a description on the procedure [here](http://www.codexperiments.com/android/2010/05/android-introduction-part-2-setting-up-your-environment/). It should work for NDK R5 too.

Hope that helps.